# is $W=\{p(x) \in P_{2} : p(1) = 2p(0)\}$ a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I need a verification of my work for the following,

Is W a subspace?
$$
W=\{p(x) \in P_{2} : p(1) = 2p(0)\}
$$

**My solution**:

let
$$
\vec{p} = a+bx+cx^{2}
$$
Then,
$\vec{0} \in W$ because,
$$
(\vec{0}=0+0x+0x^2) \rightarrow \vec{0}(1)=2\vec{0}(0)= \vec{0}
$$

$W$ is also closed under addition since,
if $\vec{q} \in W$, then
$$
(\vec{p}+\vec{q})(1) = \vec{p}(1) + \vec{q}(1) = 2\vec{p}(0) + 2\vec{q}(0)
$$

Concerning scalar multiplication. Here is where I could use a bit of help,

Assume $k$ is some scalar. Then,
$$
(k\vec{p})(1) = k(\vec{p})(1) = k\cdot2\vec{p}(0) = 2(k\vec{p})(0)
$$

But, if $k=-1$ then we have $-2\vec{p}(0)$, so does this mean we no longer have a vector space?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation is somewhat confusing. The argument should go: for $p\in W$, since $p(1) = 2p(0)$, for any scalar $k$ we have:
$$(kp)(1) = k(p(1)) = k(2p(0)) = 2(k p(0)) = 2((kp)(0))$$
showing that $kp\in W$.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I see what you're saying. I don't know why I defined the p(x) here since it's already done. I'll fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another route: Let $\phi(p) = p(1)-2p(0)$, note that $\phi$ is linear and $W = \ker \phi$ and the kernel is a subspace.